# Output in SQL Profiler has results with Database ID as NULL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, profiler

I ran profiler to filter out certain applications connecting an environment but the results has application for Database_id "**NULL**"..
Am I missing anything ?

Also another question , does all the filters applied in profiler are with **AND** condition / **OR** condition ?

Version used : 2008R2

Comment: Please add a script of the trace you were running.

Comment: What kind of event you attempt to catch?

Comment: Used profiler's standard "**Tuning template**", with filters as Database_name **like** , Host_name **Not like**,Login_name **Not_like**..

Any other details  ??

Comment: is the databaseid also null?